# Transmission slip

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, impala

I have a 2011 Chevy Impala. Once in a while the engine will rev and then kick into first gear. If I slowly press down onto gas petal it will not do this. If I start slow no problems, but if I put foot down on pedal hard it does sometimes. Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: It sounds like your transmission is starting to go out. You can try changing the fluid and see if it helps and try adding some Lucas transmission additive. Also, how many miles do you have in your car?

Comment: The comment above about the transmission going out is a little premature.  We really don't have enough info for that type of diagnosis.  Have you checked the fluid level or ever had any transmission service done?

Comment: it has 68,000 miles i checked fluid looks a little old so maybe thinking it needs to be changed

Comment: i just got the car from a dealership used about 2 months ago and warranty is up fliud looks brunt and like it wasnt changed in a little while so hoping that will help but ive read that if its old u could do more harm by draining fluid out now so not sure what should i do

Comment: @nicole Well, you have two options. Option 1 is to keep driving like that. Option 2 is to get the fluid changes and see if that helps. You can also take it back to the dealer and ask them to scan and see if there are any error codes for the transmission. These types of error codes are not usually picked up by normal OBD2 scan tools and are manufacturer specific.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you've had this resolved by now, but as a GM trans tech I can tell you the most likely cause is a failed pressure control solenoid. The solenoid coil accumulates ferrous debris and becomes less effective. The pressure is commanded down at low speed and when the controller commands a higher pressure to take off, there is low pressure for a moment until the solenoid opens up more fully. The side cover has to come off of the trans to replace it.